# discard_day and month not working rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

3.5

while doing an application . my :discard_day and month not working it still showing as eg:2013-01-01 .

in my db im using "date" datatype

```
<%= v.date_select :year, :discard_day   => true, :discard_month => true, :order => [:year], :start_year => 2000, :end_year => Time.now.year, :prompt => {:year => "Select year"} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year - 95, :field_name => 'grad_year')
```

I hope this works